# why ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required classes are added in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement form validation in Angular

here is html

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="form.emailId"  name="email" required />
```

it is adding class 
ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email

And showing red border by default.

I don't want to show Red border by default. i want to show on submit only. with HTML5 validations

Any idea? How to do resolve this

Thanks a lot

Comment: Its because of required.Sets required validation error key if the value is not entered.And thats why angular put those classes.

Comment: @squiroid: how can u tell me. i want to validate form on submit with html5 validation. Thanks

Comment: @HituBansal put novalidate attribute inside form tag.<form  novalidate="novalidate">

Comment: i did. still not workinf

Comment: You need to remove required attribute..

Comment: And check validation on click of submit button..

Comment: there is no validation is happening now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68866/discussion-between-hitu-bansal-and-ved).

Comment: I guess you want to validate fields on sbmit button click.. so you need a JS for this..

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation) is a useful article that deals with all you need to know:  specifically, [this section](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation#only-showing-errors-after-submitting-the-form):

Am including some of the text from the article for reference:

> Sometimes it is not desirable to show errors while a user is typing. The errors currently show immediately as a user is typing into the form. This happens because of Angular’s great data-binding feature. Since everything changes immediately, it can be a downside when talking about form validation.
>
> For the scenario where you only want to show errors after a form is submitted, you would adjust the above code a little bit.
>
> You would need to take away the ng-disabled on the submit button since we want a user to be able to submit a form even if it is not fully valid.
>
> You would add a variable after the form has been submitted. Inside of your submitForm() function, just add $scope.submitted = true;. This stores the submitted variable as true as soon as the form is submitted.
>
> Adjust the error rules from ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }" to ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine && submitted }". This ensures that the error will only show after the form is submitted. You would need to adjust all the other ng-class and ng-show to account for this variable.
>   Now the form only shows errors if the submitted variable is set to true.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ngForm already provides whether the form has been submitted (similar to $pristine). Also, the OP should use ngModelOptions to set when validation happens.

Comment: See [formController.$submitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$submitted)

Answer (score 0):

Usually red border is caused by bootstrap CSS module (in "form-group" or "control-group"), make sure there is no "has-feedback" nor "has-error" inside tag class (just remove them). Angular normally deal with model or back end and nothing to do with front end directly.

Other method to check this issue is to check developer tools in Chrome browser. See which CSS (usually in [elements] tab) is responsible in adding the red border.